# C# Private Font Collection -- FontStyle Does not Support Regular

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, drawing

I am working on a small project to have c# overlay some text onto a bitmap image. Everything is working great on my local machine. When I publish to project (MVC5) to a production server (Server 08 with IIS7, .net 4.5.1 is installed on the server), I get the error `Font 'Caviar Dreams' does not support style 'Regular'.`

I am loading the font .ttf file from a path on the server, and I have verified the path is correct when in production. Is there something really silly I'm missing?

Here is the code in question

```
var PFC = new PrivateFontCollection();
foreach (var Item in FontList)
{
    PFC.AddFontFile(Item);
}

var Caviar17 = new Font(PFC.Families.Where(x => x.Name == "Caviar Dreams").FirstOrDefault(), 17, FontStyle.Regular);
```

`FontList` is simply a `List<String>` of the .ttf file paths.

Comment: Does that font have a `Regular` style? Not all fonts do.

Comment: Okay this is really odd now, I thought it did, but it apparently does not. Now I'm questioning how this was ever working in the first place on my local dev machine. I don't have the font installed on my computer.

Comment: Not really sure why this got a downvote? I posted a legitimate question and the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this was incredibly simple. As @xxbbxx pointed out, the font I was using did not support `FontStyle.Regular` . Simply changing it to `FontStyle.Bold` resolved the issue.

I am still not sure how it was ever working in the first place on my local dev machine, but the issue is resolved.

Thank you, @xxbbcc!